# AWS permanent pre-signed signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-access-policy

How to get an pre-signed signature or link that have infinite expire in AWS. Or it is possible to create a permanent signature, using accesskey and secure key?

Comment: How are you currently authenticating?

Comment: If the file is not sensitive, you could make the object public and then share its URL so that there's no need for a pre-signed URL. This is typically not recommended, of course, but it may fit your use case if you're absolutely determined to share a permanent, non-expiring link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for AWS Access Keys, all other credentials, pre-signed URLs, etc. are temporary credentials.

All pre-signed URLs expire. The minimum expiration value is 1 second and the maximum is seven days (604,800 seconds).

[Authenticating Requests: Using Query Parameters (AWS Signature Version 4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html)